# UITableViewCell Not fully reloading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a UITableView to display a football schedule thats being pulled from the web. The user is given the option to skip to the next or previous year's schedule's via two buttons below the tableView. While attempting to add TV times and venue names to the schedule, I realized I would need more than the 2 lines of text the standard subtitle style cell offers, so I did some research and found a way to extend the number of lines by setting the "numberOfLines" property to 0. Since doing this, I found that the tableView data doesn't completely reload. It reloads the mainLabel and the first line of the detailLabel, but the other two lines of the detailLabel are left alone. Here is the code for populating the cells:

```
NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
NSString *cellTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellTitle];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellTitle];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
NSString *maintitle = nil;
NSString *submaintitle = nil;
if (![[locations objectAtIndex:index] isEqualToString:@"Bye"]) {
    maintitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [opponents objectAtIndex:index], [scores objectAtIndex: index]];
    submaintitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@\n%@\n%@", [dates objectAtIndex:index], [locations objectAtIndex: index], [venues objectAtIndex:index], [tvInfo objectAtIndex:index]];
    }
```

I've played around with "numberOfLines," but nothing seems to fix it. Also, I know for sure that the new data is coming in from the web without an issue. Has anyone had a similar problem or does anyone have any idea what could be causing it? If you have any issues understanding what's going on, or if you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't create different reuseIdentifier for every cell. It should be static and reusable to improve performance.
What is your cell height? It's possible that content is to large, and thats why it seems numberOfLines = 0 has no effect.

Comment: alright thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I was forgetting to reallocate the venues and locations arrays, so that explains why it wasn't updating.